# How to increase the number of activity in pg_stat_activity?

Tags: postgresql

I am working with Postgresql(Data Grip) and I am trying to run many activities at once but `pg_stat_activity` let me only do 100 activities and from the other it ignores.

How can I increase the number of activities or are there other solutions?

Comment: Why do you need more than 100 connections from a single client? That does not make any sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

`pg_stat_activity` has one row per server process.

See [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/monitoring-stats.html) in table 28.1:

> pg_stat_activity One row per server process, showing information related to the current activity of that process, such as state and current query.

and later down:

> The pg_stat_activity view will have one row per server process, showing information related to the current activity of that process.

If you want more, you need to increase the number of connections (backends) which default at 100, see [this other part of the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/runtime-config-connection.html)

> max_connections (integer)
>
> Determines the maximum number of concurrent connections to the database server. The default is typically 100 connections, but might be less if your kernel settings will not support it (as determined during initdb). This parameter can only be set at server start.